# Minimum user password length

Tags: security, cryptography, password-encryption

User accounts for online grocery shopping in Tesco here in the UK require a password of between 6 and 10 characters.  While it irritates me somewhat that they have limited the password to 10 characters (my password generator defaults to 32), the fact that they allow 6 character passwords to protect user data, including credit card details, concerns me.

Does a 6-character password represent a security risk, or are they a good example to follow?

Comment: You'll probably get better answers on http://security.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Funny you should mention Tesco; there's an interesting article about what they're doing with passwords: http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/07/lessons-in-website-security-anti.html .   In short, they're *not* a good example to follow.

Comment: Don't understand why this has been closed as off topic.  Surely asking whether 6 characters is a good standard to follow in our own password systems is a very good question to be asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 6 character password is short, probably too short. Furthermore it does not make sense to have a maximum password size, as you should only store a hash (or better the output of bcrypt, scrypt or PBKDF2).

That said, it depends on the how the system handles the password if it is secure or not. E.g. a PIN normally is about 4..6 *digits*. It's still pretty secure as your bank probably only allows you about 3 to 5 incorrect PIN entries before the PIN gets blocked.

If you would use your password as a key to encrypt data without a system to control access to said data (encrypt a file onto a harddisk that can be stolen) then 6 characters is *much* to short. You will need a full passphrase and key derivation scheme to make the encryption container secure.

Answer (score 1):

If the password contains uppercase, lowercase, numbers and symbols then a online attack would probably take 23 years and there would be more chance of the password being access via other methods ( password loss, recover method ), I personally wouldn't be happy with a 6 character password

password strength tester https://www.grc.com/haystack.htm

Answer (score 1):

Security is a tradeoff between usability and security. People should be able to remember their passwords, but it should be safe, too. Many companies are going the easy way and allow short passwords, since it should be the users responsability to choose a secure password. I don't think, an average users can handle this. Our work is to sensitize them for what is a good password.

I think the 10 character limitation represents about the same risk like the 6 character limitation. My passwords (not randomly generated) are about 12-16 characters. Therefore in your case I am not allowed to use a good password even if I had one. That policy is against our mission to sensitize people for good passwords.

About the length itself: I think a 6 character password **could** meet the security requirements if a brute force attack is impossible. (consider distributed systems as a very strong method to crack passwords).

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength) seems to have some depth about the matter.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which characters are allowed.

Anyway, six-character password is not secure enough.

You can use this security calculator: http://daleswanson.org/things/password.htm